# Using regex in a libreoffice calc macro to extract text from parentheses in a cell

Tags: regex, macros, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

Using Libreoffice 3.5.7.2 on Ubuntu 12.04.

I have text in calc cells in the form of: (IBM) Ibm Corporation.

I am trying to use regex to extract the text between the ()'s using a basic macro. This is what I have tried so far.

```
Sub getMktValue()
  Dim oDoc as Object
  Dim oSheet as Object
  Dim oCell as Object

  oDoc = ThisComponent
  oSheet = oDoc.Sheets.getByName("Income")
  'regex test code'
  oCell = oSheet.getCellByPosition(0, 1)
  stk = oCell.String()  
  myRegex = oCell.createSearchDescriptor
  myRegex.SearchRegularExpression = True
  myRegex.SearchString = "\((.*)\)"  '"[\([A-Z]\)]" "\(([^)]*)\)" "\(([^)]+)\)"'
  found = oCell.FindFirst(myRegex)
  MsgBox found.String
End Sub
```

The myRegex.SearchString line contains the various versions I have tried.  The result is always the same.  The entire contents of the cell are returned not just the text between the ()'s. Is there a way to extract just the text between the ()'s?

Thanks,  Jim

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method you tried, `.FindFirst`, finds in an [`XSearchable`](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/util/XSearchable.html) (such as a spreadsheet or range) the first occurrence of the `SearchString`.

If you want to search within a string value, then you need a different service, [`com.sun.star.util.TextSearch`](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/util/TextSearch.html).

```
Sub getMktValue()
  Dim oDoc as Object
  Dim oSheet as Object
  Dim oCell as Object

  oDoc = ThisComponent
  oSheet = oDoc.Sheets.getByName("Income")
  'regex test code'
  oCell = oSheet.getCellByPosition(0, 1)
  stk = oCell.getString() 

  oTextSearch = CreateUnoService("com.sun.star.util.TextSearch")
  oOptions = CreateUnoStruct("com.sun.star.util.SearchOptions")
  oOptions.algorithmType = com.sun.star.util.SearchAlgorithms.REGEXP
  oOptions.searchString = "\((.*)\)"
  oTextSearch.setOptions(oOptions)
  oFound = oTextSearch.searchForward(stk, 0, Len(stk))
  sFound = mid(stk, oFound.startOffset(0) + 1, oFound.endOffset(0) - oFound.startOffset(0))
  MsgBox sFound
  sFound = mid(stk, oFound.startOffset(1) + 1, oFound.endOffset(1) - oFound.startOffset(1))
  MsgBox sFound
End Sub
```

Greetings

Axel