# LibreOfiice Basic function to perform regular expression replacement

Tags: regex, replace, libreoffice-basic

###### Requirement

I wish to manipulate string values in a LibreOffice Basic macro using regular expression **replacement**? I should like to use something like `y = regex (x, "^¿(.*)\?$", "$1")` to operate on string variables (rather than cells of a document). The macro is to be used from LibreOffice Calc.

This is not for the above (trivial) problem, but a possibility that I frequently miss.

###### Apparent status

###### Only search exposed to scripts?

Of course the LibreOffice engine performs regular expression replacement (both in interactive Find/Replace and in the `REGEX` function). However, it seems that only regular expression **search** is exposed to Basic – and that is not what I am looking for. (It is provided by the somewhat cumbersome [TextSearch](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/util/TextSearch.html) service, which (if I recall correctly) can also search in string values in Basic variables.)

###### Spreadsheet functions: do not work

I thought one was meant to be able to call Calc functions in LO Basic, but calls like

```
z   = regex (x, "^¿(.*)\?$", "$1")
z   = regex (x, "^¿(.*)\?$", "$1", "g")
```

just said “Basic runtime error. Sub-procedure or function procedure not defined”.

###### Hack

As a horrible hack, one could manipulate some cells containing appropriate formulae in a scratch part of my sheet, but that has so many evident disadvantages that I would only use it *in extremis*!

###### Various sources

The question [Using regex in a libreoffice calc macro to extract text from parentheses in a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25615052/using-regex-in-a-libreoffice-calc-macro-to-extract-text-from-parentheses-in-a-ce#25628453) is about using REs to find text in cells.

Searching [the API documentation](https://api.libreoffice.org/docs) for “regular” only threw up the [TextSearch](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/util/TextSearch.html) Service mentioned above.

Several forums have posts like [this](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=19149) that only address search; I have found nothing about replacement.

Comment: See [**HERE**](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=19149)

Comment: @JohnSUN: That is only about _search_. I have clarified my question to make clearer that I want RE **replacement**.

Comment: Well, use `z =  createUnoService("com.sun.star.sheet.FunctionAccess").callFunction("REGEX", Array(x,"^¿(.*)\?$", "$1", "g"))` like as [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49429556/14094617) (thanks @Jim K!)

Comment: @JohnSUN: Thanks for the tip, which sounds like an interesting technique I have not yet come across – I shall try it out and report back.

Comment: @JohnSUN: I have just tried it out, and it worked for me. I wonder if `createUnoService` is at all expensive, but I do not suppose it would matter much in most contexts.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter - you can create it once, store it in a variable, and reuse it multiple times. The REGEX() function itself is a bit slow (like all functions that have to process text strings), but it won't be noticeable either.

Comment: A way of doing it without using worksheet functions would be to extract the non-matching sub-strings using the `com.sun.star.util.TextSearch` service and then stitch them together with the replacement text in-between. It may be fiddly to do but once encapsulated in a function no longer so.

Comment: @HowardRudd: While that technique may be applicable to many specific cases, I do not think that it is feasible for arbitrary RE replacements (with a given RE syntax), unless you build a very complex RE replacement parser; one risks creating yet another dialect for RE replacements; one would not benefit from any future extensions to the RE replacement syntax used by Calc

Comment: I wasn't suggesting the construction of a new regex to match the parts of the string not matched by the original regex. The functions provided by the `TextSearch` service return the positions of the first character and one after the last character of each match. By definition the boundaries of the matches are also the boundaries of the non-matches, so you can use them to extract the non-matches from the string just as easily as the matches.

Comment: @HowardRudd: How do you deal with capture groups? I just checked the [ICU RE docs](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/strings/regexp.html) – I see that under **Find and Replace** there are two constructs available in the replacement: `$` _n_ | `${` _name_ `}` and ` \\ ` | `\$`, which serve to specify captured groups and quoted characters. As I understand the [result of `TextSearch`](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/util/SearchResult.html) it only returns matches of the full RE, not of capture groups.

Comment: @HowardRudd: Also rolling ones own would mean missing out on any future enhancements: for starters I could image `${` _name_ `/u}` to insert a capture group converted to upper case.

Comment: `TextSearch` can cope with capture groups within the regular expression, e.g. to find repeated words, but not in the replacement text, since it doesn't have any functionality for returning the content of captured groups. You can replace "The cow cow jumped over the moon moon" with "The dog jumped over the dog" but not "The cow jumped over the moon". However, the spreadsheet function `REGEX` does allow this. So `=REGEX("The cow cow jumped over the moon moon","(\s\S+)\1","$1","g")` returns "The cow jumped over the moon". So it looks like the spreadsheet function is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Thanks to [JohnSUN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14094617/johnsun) for [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67777320/libreofiice-basic-function-to-perform-regular-expression-replacement/78098006#comment119849510_67777320) giving the solution using Calc.REGEX!*

I know of 2 approaches to RE substitutions in LibreOffice Basic:

- Call the Calc function `REGEX`. *(Uses ICU REs.)*
- Use the function `ReplaceRegex` in the `ScriptForge.String` service. *(Seems to use Python REs.)*

#### Using the Calc function `REGEX`

One can call spreadsheet functions from macros via the `callFunction` method of the service `com.sun.star.sheet.FunctionAccess`. The following function `RE_replace` uses this to perform an arbitrary RE replacement (where `report` is some error-handling):

```
Function RE_replace (y_Within as String, y_Regex as String, y_By as String, Optional y_Flags as String) as String

    Dim z_A as  Variant
    If IsMissing (y_Flags) then
        z_A = Array (y_Within, y_Regex, y_By)
    Else
        z_A = Array (y_Within, y_Regex, y_By, y_Flags)
    EndIf

    Dim z_Function_Access   as  Object  :   z_Function_Access   = createUnoService ("com.sun.star.sheet.FunctionAccess")

    Dim z_Error             as  Boolean :   z_Error             = True
    On Local Error Goto ErrHandler
        Dim z   as  String  :   z   = z_Function_Access.callFunction("REGEX", z_A)
        z_Error = False
    ErrHandler:
    On Local Error Goto 0

    If z_Error Then
        Dim z_Flags_S   as  String  :   z_Flags_S   = ""
        If not IsMissing (y_Flags) Then
            z_Flags_S   = ", '" + y_Flags + "'"
        EndIf
        report ("Error from Calc.REGEX ('" + y_Within + "', '" + y_Regex + "', '" + y_By + "'" + z_Flags_S + ")")
    EndIf
    RE_replace  = z
End Function
```

##### Notes

- I assign the result of functions to a local variable `z` to make debugging easier.
- My original version can optionally repeatedly substitute up to a given limit.
- One can cache the `FunctionAccess` object, but I do not suppose that saves much (I have not measured it).
- One could simplify this by stripping out the error handling — but that may make debugging mistakes in REs harder.
- My coding conventions work well for me! `z_` indicates a local variable and `y_` an argument; where possible I initialise a variable in the line where it is declared.
- The RE syntax supported is that of [ICU regular expressions](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/strings/regexp.html).

  - *(For a brief summary see the  [List of Regular Expressions](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.2/en-US/text/shared/01/02100001.html?&DbPAR=CALC&System=WIN) in the LibreOffice (7.2) documentation)*

*(I have slightly simplified my code, but I have briefly tested this version too)*

#### Using `ReplaceRegex` in `ScriptForge.String`

This is documented (for LO 7.2) at https://help.libreoffice.org/7.2/en-US/text/sbasic/shared/03/sf_string.html?&DbPAR=WRITER&System=UNIX , but I have not tried it. It appears to use Python RE syntax, as it refers us to the documentation of [the Python module re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Answer (score 1):

A spreadsheet demonstrating this function is at [RegEx Demo.ODS](https://mega.nz/file/uJlTBDyQ#FPXVJqXhnpjFltYZ18C5z9ZqaaHq629moDu_ZcsTI9Y)

```
Function Digits( strVal As String ) As String ' return only the digits from the input
  Const cnsSvcNam    = "com.sun.star.sheet.FunctionAccess" ' UnoService for calling      spreadsheet functions
  Const cnsShtFNm    = "REGEX"                             ' RegExp Search+Replace: what spreadsheet function we will call
' Const cnsPtnDgtYes = "[:digit:]"                         ' RegExp Search+Replace: named regular expression for yes-digits
  Const cnsPtnDgtNon = "[^0-9]"                            ' RegExp Search+Replace: named regular expression for not-digits
  Const cnsStrMpt    = ""                                  ' empty string
  Const cnsFlgGlb    = "g"                                 ' RegExp Search+Replace: flag for Global operation

  Dim strRtn   As String  ' function result
  ' variables for calling REGEX( Text ; Expression [ ; [ Replacement ] [ ; Flags|Occurrence ] ] ) ' spreadsheet function signature
  Dim strSch   As String  ' RegExp Search+Replace: text       to search in
  Dim strExp   As String  ' RegExp Search+Replace: expression to match  on
  Dim strRpl   As String  ' RegExp Search+Replace: string     to insert as replacements
  Dim strFlg   As String  ' RegExp Search+Replace: flags / occurrence
  Dim arrFnc() As String  ' paramter-values to pass as arguments to spreadsheet function (array of strings)

  ' Drop all non-digit characters from input
' strRtn = RegEx( strVal, "[:digit:]", "", "g" ) ' RegEx is not defined in scope of Basic code, but it *is* defined as a spreadsheet function
  strSch = strVal                                                          ' text    to search in
  strExp = cnsPtnDgtNon                                                    ' pattern to match  on: match all non-digits
  strRpl = cnsStrMpt                                                       ' replacement data    : replace with nothing
  strFlg = cnsFlgGlb                                                       ' operation flags     : do this for all instances found
  arrFnc = Array( strSch, strExp, strRpl, strFlg )                         ' populate parameter values / arguments to   spreadsheet function
  strRtn = createUnoService( cnsSvcNam ).callFunction( cnsShtFNm, arrFnc ) ' execute                                    spreadsheet function

  Digits = strRtn                                                          ' pass result back to caller
End Function ' Digits
```

Comment: What is that site, which asks me to log in? This is basically JohnSUN’s comment, but having it in an answer is useful. I have preferred to factor out all the kerfuffle into an extra function and and use that to make wrappers for those spreadsheet functions I find I want.

Comment: Aha: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mega_(service) tells us that it offers free encrypted distributed cloud storage. That article sounds in at least one place like advertising, but interesting.

Comment: Yeah I looked at the file-attachment sites that SO recommended: one was not-found and the other was hot garbage. Can anyone suggest a fileshare host that does not want a login and not Ggl or M$ft?